# How can i split an integer number into a group of two without using arrays?

Tags: java, math, integer, numbers

I want to split a integer number in groups of two without using arrays and math library, eg 1245 into 12 and 45 and 123 into 01 and 23. I thought about /100 and % 100, eg 2330 => 23 30 but that method depends on the number of digits...

I expect to get  groups of two

Comment: I don't see the relevance of arrays to the problem. Why don't you want it to depend on the number of digits?

Comment: @JohnColeman it can but if  it do so, i have a different case for every number of digits which is inefficient isn't it? Most of the Solutions for the problem i saw are done with arrays.

Comment: How are you going to use the results? For example, what to do with `9876543 => 09 87 65 43`?

Comment: @JohnColeman i want to do it without Math Library (Java is the programming language)

Comment: Why not simply turn the number into a string, and then loop over that string, and fetch substrings?

Comment: And thing is: what have you tried before? You see, this community is about helping people to solve their problems/homework themselves. To me, it rather looks like you basically gave us your (homework) requirements, and now expect others to do the work for you. That is not a good way to learn programming. You learn programming by programming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convert to string, slice, and convert back approach:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   ArrayList<Integer> pairs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   int n = 1234567;
   String s = Integer.toString(n);
   int start = 0;
   if(s.length() % 2 == 1)
   {
       start = 1;
       pairs.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,1)));
   }
   for(int i = start; i < s.length()-1; i+=2)
   {
       pairs.add(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i,i+2)));  
   }
   //test:
   for(int p : pairs)
   {
       System.out.println(p);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
1
23
45
67
```